# Java Double to String with dot separator and infinite number of digits after the decimal

Tags: java

I want to parse a java double value to string but with dot separator and  infinite number of digits after the decimal. What I want to achived:

```
33.123456789 -> "33.123456789"
1.234 -> "1.234"
2.0 -> "2"
```

I have my sample code but it doesn't work corectly.

```
DecimalFormat DOUBLE_FORMAT = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DOUBLE_FORMAT.applyPattern("#.####");
```

Which gives me:

```
33.123456789 -> "33.1234"
1.234 -> "1.234"
2.0 -> "2"
```

So it not work how I want to. Any idea ? ;)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: You use four '#' after the dot so you will get four digits after the dot when parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles are just an approximation, a sum of 2<sup>-i</sup>. Hence

```
33.123456789 * 100 != 3312.3456789
```

And

```
double x = 33.123456789;
String s = String.valueOf(x);
// No guarantee that s has the same number of decimals.
```

And for the precise numerical type BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(33.123456789); // Bad
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("33.123456789"); // Good, with correct precision.
```

So in your case, one must consider switching to BigDecimal. Or accept `String.valueOf` / `Double.toString`.

**BigDecimal**, though, has that unlimited precision.

Answer (score 2):

Just add more #,i.e.

```
DOUBLE_FORMAT.applyPattern("#.######################");
```

Comment: Because I don't want to add 200 times '#' :)

Comment: @mardok Well, double does not have infinitly many digits, it has only 52 bits which is roughly 17 decimal digits, so 17 times # will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `BigDecimal` and pass it `String.valueOf`.

```
double d = 123456789.0;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(d)).toPlainString());
double dd = 33.123456789;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(dd)).toPlainString());
```

**Output**

```
123456789
33.123456789
```

Comment: Because for 123456789.0 it gives me "1.23456789E8" where I expect "123456789"

Comment: @mardok do you need to keep the `.0` in your String representation?